# Why do we get an Invalid Type error only after Summer '20 upgrade?

Tags: apex, summer20

After upgrading to Summer '20, we get an invalid type error for dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c in existing tests and classes.

I can see a dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c record in the UI:
lightning/r/dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c/a0K3I000000ijo8UAA/view

[image: screenshot of DocuSignAccountConfiguration]

But if I try to create this simple Apex class in the Salesforce setup UI:

```
public class Summer20Test {
    List<dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c> docusignConfigs = [
        SELECT Id, dsfs__OrganizationId__c, dsfs__AccountId__c, dsfs__DocuSignEnvironment__c
        FROM dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c
    ];
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c at line 2 column 9
```

We have other code that references other objects from dsfs and other packages that don't cause an error.

Perhaps related: before Summer 20, we found that we couldn't save classes that reference dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c using the Tooling API (specifically Developer Console and our IDE). We chalked it up to [this issue](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l8a5AAA), but when opening a case with Salesforce, they suggested we follow up with DocuSign.

Comment: Does the user profile have access to `dsfs__DocuSignAccountConfiguration__c`?